# jQuery add event to every child of Node

Tags: javascript, jquery

the node <'ul'> I received asynchronously contains <'li'> inputs. I need to add event to every li.

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li><input id="red" type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><input id="black" type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><input id="white" type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>
```

As I understand I need to use smth like:

```
$(document).on('change', '.parent' ....})
```

And probably I need ***.each***. 
Can you describe how to use this functionality in this certain case?

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '.parent input' ....})`

Comment: You don't need .each. Use `$(document).on('change', '.parent input', function() {})` and use `this` / `$(this)` inside the handler to get the `<input>`.

Comment: You don't even need `$(document)` just `$('.parent input').change(function() {})` will work

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan The `<ul>` is added dynamically; your solution requires to reassign the event handler each time the list is loaded. Delegating doesn't.

Comment: Duplicate: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the event handler to only parent element, the `.parent`, and the event only needs to bubble up from the clicked `li` to `ul`:

```
$('.parent').on('change', 'li > input:checkbox', function(){...});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.parent').on('change', 'li > input:checkbox', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li><input id="red" type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><input id="black" type="checkbox"></li>
  <li><input id="white" type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.parent').on('change', 'li input', function()})`